# NameError in dictionary in utils file

Tags: python, dictionary, jupyter-notebook, python-3.6, nameerror

I have been working on a Jupyter Notebook to import a google spreadsheet and do some manipulation on the original spreadsheet using pandas.

I now want to "turn" my notebook into a .py file that I can execute in the future from the Terminal, and the first thing that I am doing is that I am taking the functions I defined in the Notebook in a separate utils.py file.

One of these functions uses the keys and values of a dictionary (that I also moved in the utils.py file), but when I call the function in the notebook I get a nameerror that tells me that the dictionary is not defined.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-26b9f9a7246e> in <module>()
----> 1 cols_ls = columns_to_keep("Score")

~/my_CS109a/content/utils.py in columns_to_keep(column_str)
      5 sections_dict["1"] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
      6 sections_dict["2"] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
----> 7 sections_dict["3"] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
      8 sections_dict["4"] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
      9 sections_dict["5"] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

NameError: name 'sections_dict' is not defined
```

This is how I imported the utils file and how I called the function in the Notebook.

```
from utils import *
# Say I want to pass the string Score to the function 
cols_ls = columns_to_keep("Score")
```

My `utils.py` is copy pasted below:

```
# Create empty dictionary to map every section title to the number of questions they contain
sections_dict = dict()

# Add all section names as key and a list of the questions they contain as list 
sections_dict["1"] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
sections_dict["2"] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
sections_dict["3"] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
sections_dict["4"] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
sections_dict["5"] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
sections_dict["6"] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
sections_dict["7"] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
sections_dict["8"] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
sections_dict["9"] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
sections_dict["10"] = [1, 2, 3, 4]    


# Function to create the list of columns to keep from the copy DataFrame. Takes a string as an argument and 
# iteratively creates the names of the columns to keep extracting the number of the section and the the questions
# from the sections_dict object. Returns list of strings of the format ColumnName_SectionNumber_QuestionNumber. 

def columns_to_keep (column_str = "name"):
    columns_to_keep_ls = []
    for key_i, value_ls in sections_dict.items():
        for question_i in range(len(value_ls)):
            columns_to_keep_ls.append("{}_{}_{}".format(column_str, key_i, value_ls[question_i]))
    return (columns_to_keep_ls)


# Create a function that takes the name of a company and the section over which to calculate the score, it should output a float as the score of the section.

def calculate_section_scores(company_name="name", section=0):
    ls = (
        scores_df.loc["{}".format(company_name)]
        # Hard code the '1' as I will always want to start from the 1st question.
        # Get length of list in questions_list corresponding to last question in that section.
        ["Score_{}_1".format(section):"Score_{}_{}".format(section, len(questions_list[section-1]))]

    ).values[:]

    score_flt = (pd.to_numeric(ls).sum())/max_scores_ls[section-1]

    return (score_flt)
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the right code?  It seems very odd that the previous two lines for `sections_dict["1"]` and `sections_dict["2"]` would work, but then get that error for `sections_dict["3"]`.  Also, the error message indicates that those lines are inside the `columns_to_keep()` function, which does not match your posted code.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for having a look. Yes that is the right code, I had pasted the error of when I had initiated the dict inside the function, but regardless of where the dict is i get the same error. I also don't understand why it would work on Jupyter or why it would work for the first two rows...

Comment: I was unable to reproduce. Do you have an unprintable character in that line? Have you tried initializing sections_dict as {"1": [...], "2": [...], ... } ?